# Python: Replace with regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace part of a string. I was looking through the Python documentation and found re.sub.

```
import re
s = '<textarea id="Foo"></textarea>'
output = re.sub(r'<textarea.*>(.*)</textarea>', 'Bar', s)
print output

>>>'Bar'
```

I was expecting this to print `'<textarea id="Foo">Bar</textarea>'` and not 'bar'.

Could anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: The usual recommendation is that you not use regex for HTML. It is a longstanding response on this site, with some classic responses, culminating in this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Yep, was thinking to use regex since it's really small piece but switched to BeautifulSoup instead.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Instead of capturing the part you want to *replace* you can capture the parts you want to *keep* and then refer to them using a reference `\1` to include them in the substituted string.

Try this instead:

```
output = re.sub(r'(<textarea.*>).*(</textarea>)', r'\1Bar\2', s)
```

Also, assuming this is HTML you should consider using an HTML parser for this task, for example [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: I think you mean `r'\1Bar\3'`.

Comment: As mentioned, best not to parse your own html.  But for the sake of completeness, should point out that by default regular expressions are greedy, so in this example, the first capture group would match up to the **last** open angle bracket.  If the string had tags inside the `<textarea>`, those would be included inside the match.  It would be better to use the question mark to prevent this:
  `r'(<textarea.*?>).*(</textarea>)'`

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just use the search function instead:

```
match=re.search(r'(<textarea.*>).*(</textarea>)', s)
output = match.group(1)+'bar'+match.group(2)
print output
>>>'<textarea id="Foo">bar</textarea>'
```