# Replace part of the string matching the pattern

Tags: python, regex, match

It's my first Python day, so please excuse me for this question

The Problem:
in a file replace every occurrence of 
**trim(column_name)** with **TRIM (TRIM (CHR (09) FROM column_name))**. I've already sorted out how to do a pattern search and acquainted myself with the re.sub() function.

the pattern that matches my case is

```
p = re.compile ('trim\([a-z0-9_]+\)',re.I)
```

but how do I replace the matching pattern preserving the column name???

The needed output is, for example, as follows:

```
input: select trim(API12), trim(FIELD_CODE) from table
output: select TRIM (TRIM (CHR (09) FROM API12)), TRIM (TRIM (CHR (09) FROM FIELD_CODE)) from table
```

Comment: use a backreference `\1`

Comment: could you please elaborate on this one a little bit more?

Comment: I think this answer will be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997525/python-replace-with-regex

Comment: that is what im currently doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
import re
i = 'select trim(API12), trim(FIELD_CODE) from table'
re.sub(r"trim\((\w+)\)", r"TRIM (TRIM (CHR (09) FROM \1))", i)
```

### Explain

1. You don't have to use flag `re.I`, use `\w` instead, it's equivalence to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.
2. `\(\)` means the normal parenthesis, `()` means the grouping
3. use `\1` to render the first match group, `\2` for second one.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = 'select trim(API12), trim(FIELD_CODE) from table'
print re.sub(r'trim\((?P<col>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)', 'TRIM (TRIM (CHR (09) FROM \g<col>))', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just sorted this one out for myself

Thanks for your help!

```
import re

line = "select trim(API12), trim(FIELD_CODE) from dual"

output = re.sub(r'trim\(([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)',r'TRIM (TRIM (CHR (09) FROM\1))',line)

print output
```

**>> select TRIM (TRIM (CHR (09) FROM API12)), TRIM (TRIM (CHR (09) FROM FIELD_CODE)) from dual**