# Regex for dot, space and newline

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex for python that replaces a dot, space or newline (and any combination of these) with a single comma. I don't understand why my regex is not working.

```
    newline = line.replace("[\. \\n]+",",")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**sub**](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) to be able to use regex in search replace.

```
# your code goes here
import re
line = "something with space . dot";
line = re.sub(r'[. \n]+', ",", line);
print line;
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Cxxggk)

Answer (score 0):

The characters in between the square brackets ("character class") are literals so don't need escaping. Try `[. \n]+` instead.

**Edit**

According to this answer [Python string.replace regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16720541/1425848) `replace` does not recognise regex and you need to use `sub`

Comment: It did not work. Normally I can get it work in R. Not sure if python is any issue here.

Comment: Could be. I'm not well up on Python. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3997525/1425848

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/16720541/1425848 `replace` does not recognise regex and you need to use `sub`