# In Python I want to replace <phrase>the cow jumped over the moon</phrase> with <phrase>the_cow_jumped_over_the_moon</phrase>

Tags: python, string, replace

In Python I want to replace `<phrase>the cow jumped over the moon</phrase>` with `<phrase>the_cow_jumped_over_the_moon</phrase>` 
so only within `<phrase>` and `</phrase>` blank spaces should be replaced with _ which is an underscore

All other places should not be changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Replace with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997525/python-replace-with-regex)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the replace method to do your task

```
msg1 = "the cow jumped over the moon"
print(str(msg1).replace(" ","_"))
```

Output:

```
the_cow_jumped_over_the_moon
```